# Creating a Windows Service to open a program- Delphi

Tags: delphi, windows-services

I'm creating a Windows Service with Delphi. What my service needs to do is basically open a program.
In my code I'm using `WinExec(aux,SW_SHOWNORMAL);`. When I start and run the service nothing appears to be done, but when I look in TaskManager the program that my service should open is in the list and in the Username Column appears SYSTEM.

So the program is opening but it doesn't show in the screen.
I did a research in Google and found some functions like `CreateProcess` but I don't know how to use it.
What am I doing wrong?

Sorry about my bad english.

Comment: If you are using Windows Vista o 7 then check this MSDN article [Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx)

Comment: @Daniel Your English is superbly fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Services always run in Session 0.  A process started by a service runs in the service's Session by default, unless the service uses `CreateProcessAsUser()` to run the process in a different Session.

In XP and earlier, the first user to log in also runs in Session 0 (subsequent users to login run in Sessions 1+).  Thus, if the service is marked as Interactive when it is installed and it runs a process that has a UI, a user running in Session 0 can see the UI.

In Vista and later, this is no longer possible.  Users never run in Session 0 anymore, and services cannot be marked as Interactive anymore.  This is known as "Session 0 Isolation".  A service must use `CreateProcessAsUser()` now in order to run a UI process in an Interactive Session so a user can see it.

Refer to MSDN for more details:

[Session 0 Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756986.aspx)

[Impact of Session 0 Isolation on Services and Drivers in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx)

[Calling CreateProcessAsUser() from service](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/31bfa13d-982b-4b1a-bff3-2761ade5214f)

[Launching an interactive process from Windows Service in Windows Vista and later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx)

[CreateProcessAsUser function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! `CreateProcessAsUser()`will help. Another thing, can you exemplify `CreateProcessAsUser()` uses? I'm getting trouble with parameters.

Comment: The articles I linked to show you how to use `CreateProcessAsUser()` in a service, and there is plenty of information available online about it, so I'm not going to explain it here. Just know that the difference between `WinExec()` (which uses `CreateProcess()` internally) and `CreateProcessAsUser()` is that `CreateProcess()` runs the new process in the user account of the calling process, whereas `CreateProcessAsUser()` runs the new process in the specified user account instead. This is important when trying to access the user's Session from a service Session.